# ffmpeg live smooth streaming stereo to 2 mono channels

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream live smooth streaming using ffmpeg, which I can manage just fine.
However, the input audio is a single stereo channel, which I need to split to separate audio feeds, as they are in different languages.

I've searched for a couple days trying all sorts of combinations, but cannot find one that works.

My basic streaming command is:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 720x576 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 25 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -threads 4 -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -map 0:v -b:v:0 1300k -s:v:0 720x576 -map 0:v -b:v:1 900k -s:v:1 640x480 -map 0:v -b:v:2 500k -s:v:2 480x360 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:0 http://192.168.1.1/live/channel1/channel1.isml/Streams(video)
```

So the -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:0 gives me 2 channels of identical audio, both with the two languages on each, I have tried the pan option, which is one of the only ones that works, but gives me no audio:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 720x576 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 25 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=1:c0=c0[left]; [0:1]pan=1:c0=c1[right]" -threads 4 -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -map 0:v -b:v:0 1300k -s:v:0 720x576 -map 0:v -b:v:1 900k -s:v:1 640x480 -map 0:v -b:v:2 500k -s:v:2 480x360 -map "[left]" -map "[right]" http://192.168.101.10:82/live/channel1/channel1.isml/Streams(video)
```

I get warnings when using the pan option, but nothing that I can see that would prevent the audio from streaming:

```
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 0000000002772ee0] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
Single channel layout '1' is interpreted as a number of channels, switch to the syntax '1c' otherwise it will be interpreted as a channel layout number in a later version
```

I have updated my command to use the | separator, to no further effect.

This is using Zeranoe ffmpeg for Windows 64bit, version N-60386-g9c978f2
Video and Audio are provided by a Decklink SDI capture card, audio is on Group 1 Channel 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I think I'm going round in circles!

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg command and console output for your command using the pan audio filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by seperating the -map audio commands
Seems that ffmpeg cannot handle more than one -map command for audio to isml

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 720x576 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 25 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -threads 4 -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=1:c0=c0[left]" -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -map 0:v -b:v:0 1300k -s:v:0 720x576 -map 0:v -b:v:1 900k -s:v:1 640x480 -map 0:v -b:v:2 500k -s:v:2 480x360 -map "[left]" http://192.168.101.10:82/live/channel1/channel1.isml/Streams(video) -threads 4 -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=1:c0=c1[right]" -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -map 0:v -b:v:0 1300k -s:v:0 720x576 -map 0:v -b:v:1 900k -s:v:1 640x480 -map 0:v -b:v:2 500k -s:v:2 480x360 -map "[right]" http://192.168.101.10:82/live/channel1/channel1.isml/Streams(video)
```